# How to fix .remove() not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a personal website and have encountered a problem with .remove() JS function. I am trying to select all elements with "no-load" class and remove the class from the element.

I have tried selecting elements with IDs, querySelectorAll, getElementByClassName but everytime .remove() returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined"

I have an element main with id = main. It has 2 classes, namely "no-load" and "opacity-zero".

```html
<main class = "no-load opacity-zero" id = "main">
```

Selecting it in JavaScript console

```
> main
```

yields correct result:

```html
< <main class = "no-load opacity-zero" id = "main">
```

Selecting it's classlist also works:

```
> main.classlist
< DOMTokenList(2) ["no-load", "opacity-zero", value: "no-load opacity-zero"]
```

Trying to remove a class however, results in:

```
> main.classlist.remove("no-load")
< Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
```

I can't seem to solve this bug, please do help.

Comment: `classlist` or `classList`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`classlist` should be `classList`

It would also be a good idea to do a null check against your element so that if the element isn't found, `classList` will return an error.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.myClass');
console.log('before remove', div.classList.value);
if (div && div.classList) {
  div.classList.remove('myClass');
}
console.log('after remove', div.classList.value);
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
```